# Extract translations from tornado template

Tags: python, internationalization, translation, tornado

I'm trying to use `python-babel` to extract translations from tornado templates.

I have tried some solutions, and none of them is perfect.

### solution one

Use `python` as extractor:

```
# babel.cfg
[python: **/server/templates/**.html]
```

It works most of time, but won't work if there are some translations inside `script` blocks:

```
<script> var a = {{ _("won't be extracted") }} </script>
```

### solution two

Just let tornado use jinja2 template engine, it works but not pretty.

### solution three

Use `tornado-babel`, it is just an outdated library without python3 support.

---

Any suggestion?

Comment: `<script> var a = {{ _("won't be extracted") }} </script>` as a string(not variable), so `my_page.replace("won't be extracted",my_script_output)` . **my_script_output** It is absolutely necessary to have an output, it cannot be connected to the generator or function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I just use jinja2 template engine. Highly recommend tornado's team to use jinja2 template engine! Do not waste time any more.